# Why does Ubuntu 20.04 installer lag, have bad resolution, and can't find hard drive partitions, but Ubuntu 22.04 has 0 issues?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, 22.04, crash

I was trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop recently, and the first thing I immediately noticed was that it was pretty slow, and the GUI windows didn't fit in the 800x600 resolution I was forced into. The slow down improved but wasn't completely fixed after I switched to using a USB-C based live USB (from USB-A 2.0). Once I got to selecting hard drive partitions, it shows nothing and trying to select any option to add / change partitions causes the entire runtime to hang, requiring a hardware shutdown.

I had all but given up, but then I figured I'd give 22 a go. 22's installer not only had a great resolution, but all windows fit, the installer was snappy and responsive, and best of all I could actually find and delegate partitions on my hard drive.

So what gives? I'd rather have 20 because of old software I want to update, but I can make do with 22. Anyone have any ideas?

Hardware:

- i9-13900H (12 core, 20-threads)
- 16GB DDR5 Ram
- NVMe Micron 1TB SSD
- OLED Screen (in case that's relevant)?

Comment: 22.04 has newer Linux kernel that supports your fresh hardware